# Radial progress bar doesn't change color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've found animated radial progress bar using CSS mostly. The main thing is I need to display 227%.

Animation I want to make is to change bar color after 100% and 200%.
I've been trying to use .css and also .removeClass(loader-spiner) which is main class and .addClass (loader-spiner-100), also I've been trying to use .attr to add my own style but it outputs those are not functions or smth like that.

Can you help me with this, please?

http://jsfiddle.net/artofbw/qgqren9e/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        function renderProgress(progress)
    {
        progress = Math.floor(progress);

        if(progress<25){
            var angle = -90 + (progress/100)*360;
            $(".animate-0-25-b").css("transform","rotate("+angle+"deg)");
        }
        else if(progress>=25 && progress<50){
            var angle = -90 + ((progress-25)/100)*360;
            $(".animate-0-25-b").css("transform","rotate(0deg)");
            $(".animate-25-50-b").css("transform","rotate("+angle+"deg)");
        }
        else if(progress>=50 && progress<75){
            var angle = -90 + ((progress-50)/100)*360;
            $(".animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css("transform","rotate(0deg)");
            $(".animate-50-75-b").css("transform","rotate("+angle+"deg)");
        }
        else if(progress>=75 && progress<=100){
            var angle = -90 + ((progress-75)/100)*360;
            $(".animate-50-75-b, .animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css("transform","rotate(0deg)");
            $(".animate-75-100-b").css("transform","rotate("+angle+"deg)");
        }
        if(progress==100) {
            alert('first');
        }
        if(progress==200) {
            alert('second');
        }
        if(progress==227){
            clearInterval(int);
        }
        $(".text").html(progress+"%");
    }

    function clearProgress()
    {
        $(".animate-75-100-b, .animate-50-75-b, .animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css("transform","rotate(90deg)");
    }

    var i=0;
    var int = setInterval(function (){
                    i++;
                    if(i>227) {
                        i=0
                        clearProgress();
                    }
                    renderProgress(i);
    }, 50);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a second set of rules to accommodate for the progress being 100+ would allow you to essentially reset it, though it does add a bit more code.

Below is simply reusing your original set of rules after going over 100.

```
    else if(progress<125){
        var angle = -90 + (progress/100)*360;
        $(".animate-0-25-b").css("transform","rotate("+angle+"deg)");
    }
    else if(progress>=125 && progress<150){
        var angle = -90 + ((progress-25)/100)*360;
        $(".animate-0-25-b").css("transform","rotate(0deg)");
        $(".animate-25-50-b").css("transform","rotate("+angle+"deg)");
    }
    else if(progress>=150 && progress<175){
        var angle = -90 + ((progress-50)/100)*360;
        $(".animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css("transform","rotate(0deg)");
        $(".animate-50-75-b").css("transform","rotate("+angle+"deg)");
    }
    else if(progress>=175 && progress<=200){
        var angle = -90 + ((progress-75)/100)*360;
        $(".animate-50-75-b, .animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css("transform","rotate(0deg)");
        $(".animate-75-100-b").css("transform","rotate("+angle+"deg)");
    }
```

Comment: Ok, you helped me a little. I've been looking for solution that inherit new background, but you directed me pretty good :) thanks. Here is my solution :) http://jsfiddle.net/artofbw/mocr3ss4/

Answer (score 0):

The color of the circle is determined by the borderColor of the `.loader-spiner`. You can easily set this using something like `$('.loader-spiner').css({'border-color': '#f00'});`.
Here is an example (I also made a new variable `progressRound` to "reset" the loader-spinner):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        function renderProgress(progress)
    {
        progress = Math.floor(progress);
        
        var progressRound = progress;
        while(progressRound > 100){
            progressRound -= 100;
            clearProgress();
        }

        if(progressRound<25){
            var angle = -90 + (progressRound/100)*360;
            $(".animate-0-25-b").css("transform","rotate("+angle+"deg)");
        }
        else if(progressRound>=25 && progressRound<50){
            var angle = -90 + ((progressRound-25)/100)*360;
            $(".animate-0-25-b").css("transform","rotate(0deg)");
            $(".animate-25-50-b").css("transform","rotate("+angle+"deg)");
        }
        else if(progressRound>=50 && progressRound<75){
            var angle = -90 + ((progressRound-50)/100)*360;
            $(".animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css("transform","rotate(0deg)");
            $(".animate-50-75-b").css("transform","rotate("+angle+"deg)");
        }
        else if(progressRound>=75 && progressRound<=100){
            var angle = -90 + ((progressRound-75)/100)*360;
            $(".animate-50-75-b, .animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css("transform","rotate(0deg)");
            $(".animate-75-100-b").css("transform","rotate("+angle+"deg)");
        }
        if(progress==100) {
            $(".loader-spiner").css({ "border-color": "#f00" });
        }
        if(progress==200) {
            $(".loader-spiner").css({ "border-color": "#0f0" });
        }
        if(progress==227){
            clearInterval(int);
        }
        $(".text").html(progress+"%");
    }

    function clearProgress()
    {
        $(".animate-75-100-b, .animate-50-75-b, .animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css("transform","rotate(90deg)");
    }

    var i=0;
    var int = setInterval(function (){
                    i++;
                    if(i>227) {
                        i=0
                        clearProgress();
                    }
                    renderProgress(i);
    }, 50);
    
});
```

```css
.loader{
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.loader-bg
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #f7f7f7;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.spiner-holder-1
{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.spiner-holder-2
{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.loader-spiner
{
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #66c1d1;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}  

.loader-spiner-100
{
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid black;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}  
  .animate-0-25-a
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.animate-0-25-b
{   
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.animate-25-50-a
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.animate-25-50-b
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.animate-50-75-a
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.animate-50-75-b
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    transform-origin:100% 100%;
}
.animate-75-100-a
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.animate-75-100-b
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.text
{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:26%;
    font-size: 12px;     
    color: #a1a5a5;
    font-family: 'aileronlight';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 200px;">
              <div style="width: 33.3%; height: 200px; float:left; position: relative;">




                <div class="loader" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; top: 47px;left: 67px;">
                        <div class="loader-bg" style="border-width: 10px;">
                            <div class="text" style="font-size: 22px; padding-top:32%;"></div>
                        </div>        
                            <div class="spiner-holder-1 animate-0-25-a">
                                        <div class="spiner-holder-2 animate-0-25-b">
                                            <div class="loader-spiner" style="border-width: 10px;"></div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="spiner-holder-1 animate-25-50-a">
                                        <div class="spiner-holder-2 animate-25-50-b">
                                            <div class="loader-spiner" style="border-width: 10px;"></div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="spiner-holder-1 animate-50-75-a">
                                        <div class="spiner-holder-2 animate-50-75-b">
                                            <div class="loader-spiner" style="border-width: 10px;"></div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="spiner-holder-1 animate-75-100-a">
                                        <div class="spiner-holder-2 animate-75-100-b">
                                            <div class="loader-spiner" style="border-width: 10px;"></div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>

                    </div>



              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I tried it also, with $('.loader-spiner').css({'border': '5px solid black'}); and it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: I added the modified code to the answer. Does this help you to understand what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 function renderProgress(progress) {
  progress = Math.floor(progress);

  if (progress < 25) {
   angle = -90 + (progress / 100) * 360;
   $(".animate-0-25-b").css(fillRotateStyles(angle));
  } else if (progress >= 25 && progress < 50) {
   angle = -90 + ((progress - 25) / 100) * 360;
   $(".animate-0-25-b").css(fillRotateRestart(0));
   $(".animate-25-50-b").css(fillRotateStyles(angle));
  } else if (progress >= 50 && progress < 75) {
   var angle = -90 + ((progress - 50) / 100) * 360;
   $(".animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css(fillRotateRestart(0));
   $(".animate-50-75-b").css(fillRotateStyles(angle));
  } else if (progress >= 75 && progress <= 100) {
   angle = -90 + ((progress - 75) / 100) * 360;
   $(".animate-50-75-b, .animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css(fillRotateRestart(0));
   $(".animate-75-100-b").css(fillRotateStyles(angle));
  } else if (progress > 100 && progress <= 125) {
   angle = -90 + (progress / 100) * 360;
   $(".animate-75-100-b, .animate-50-75-b, .animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css(fillRotateRestart(0));
   $(".animate-100-125-b").css(fillRotateStyles(angle));
  } else if (progress > 125 && progress <= 150) {
   angle = -90 + ((progress - 25) / 100) * 360;
   $(".animate-100-125, .animate-75-100-b, .animate-50-75-b, .animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css(fillRotateRestart(0));
   $(".animate-125-150-b").css(fillRotateStyles(angle));
  } else if (progress > 150 && progress <= 175) {
   angle = -90 + ((progress - 50) / 100) * 360;
   $(".animate-125-150-b, .animate-100-125-b, .animate-75-100-b, .animate-50-75-b, .animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css(fillRotateRestart(0));
   $(".animate-150-175-b").css(fillRotateStyles(angle));
  } else if (progress > 175 && progress <= 200) {
   angle = -90 + ((progress - 75) / 100) * 360;
   $(".animate-150-175, .animate-125-150-b, .animate-100-125-b, .animate-75-100-b, .animate-50-75-b, .animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css(fillRotateRestart(0));
   $(".animate-175-200-b").css(fillRotateStyles(angle));
  } else if (progress > 200 && progress <= 225) {
   angle = -90 + (progress / 100) * 360;
   $(".animate-175-200-b, .animate-150-175-b, .animate-125-150-b, .animate-100-125-b, .animate-75-100-b, .animate-50-75-b, .animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css(fillRotateRestart(0));
   $(".animate-200-225-b").css(fillRotateStyles(angle));
  } else if (progress > 225 && progress <= 250) {
   angle = -90 + ((progress - 25) / 100) * 360;
   $(".animate-200-225-b, .animate-175-200-b, .animate-150-175-b, .animate-125-150-b, .animate-100-125-b, .animate-75-100-b, .animate-50-75-b, .animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css(fillRotateRestart(0));
   $(".animate-225-250-b").css(fillRotateStyles(angle));
  }
  if (progress == 227) {
   clearInterval(int);
  }
  $(".text").html(progress + "%");
 }

 function clearProgress() {
  $(".animate-75-100-b, .animate-50-75-b, .animate-25-50-b, .animate-0-25-b").css(fillRotateRestart(90));
 }

 var i = 0;
 var int = setInterval(function () {
  i++;
  if (i > 227) {
   i = 0
   clearProgress();
  }
  renderProgress(i);
 }, 50);

 function fillRotateStyles(angle) {
  return {
   '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
   '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
   '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
   '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
   'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
  };
 }

 function fillRotateRestart(amount) {
  return {
   '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + amount + 'deg)',
   '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + amount + 'deg)',
   '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + amount + 'deg)',
   '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + amount + 'deg)',
   'transform': 'rotate(' + amount + 'deg)'
  };
 }

});
```

```css
.loader {
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -o-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.loader-bg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 5px solid #c6c6c6;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.spiner-holder-1 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 background: transparent;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.spiner-holder-2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: transparent;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.loader-spiner {
 width: 200%;
 height: 200%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 5px solid #478792;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.loader-spiner-100 {
 width: 200%;
 height: 200%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 5px solid #66c1d1;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.loader-spiner-200 {
 width: 200%;
 height: 200%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 5px solid #478792;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}


.animate-0-25-a {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-0-25-b {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-25-50-a {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
 transform: rotate(180deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-25-50-b {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-50-75-a {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
 transform: rotate(270deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-50-75-b {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-75-100-a {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-75-100-b {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-100-125-a {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-100-125-b {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-125-150-a {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
 transform: rotate(180deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-125-150-b {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-150-175-a {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
 transform: rotate(270deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-150-175-b {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-175-200-a {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-175-200-b {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.animate-200-225-a {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-200-225-b {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.animate-225-250-a {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
 transform: rotate(180deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.animate-225-250-b {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.text {
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 34%;
 font-size: 22px;
 color: #a1a5a5;
 font-family: 'aileronlight';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar">

<div>



 <div class="loader">
  <div class="loader-bg" style="border-width: 10px;">
   <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="spiner-holder-1 animate-0-25-a">
   <div class="spiner-holder-2 animate-0-25-b">
    <div class="loader-spiner" style="border-width: 10px;"></div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="spiner-holder-1 animate-25-50-a">
   <div class="spiner-holder-2 animate-25-50-b">
    <div class="loader-spiner" style="border-width: 10px;"></div>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="spiner-holder-1 animate-50-75-a">
   <div class="spiner-holder-2 animate-50-75-b">
    <div class="loader-spiner" style="border-width: 10px;"></div>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="spiner-holder-1 animate-75-100-a">
   <div class="spiner-holder-2 animate-75-100-b">
    <div class="loader-spiner" style="border-width: 10px;"></div>
   </div>
  </div>



  <div class="spiner-holder-1 animate-100-125-a">
   <div class="spiner-holder-2 animate-100-125-b">
    <div class="loader-spiner-100" style="border-width: 10px;"></div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="spiner-holder-1 animate-125-150-a">
   <div class="spiner-holder-2 animate-125-150-b">
    <div class="loader-spiner-100" style="border-width: 10px;"></div>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="spiner-holder-1 animate-150-175-a">
   <div class="spiner-holder-2 animate-150-175-b">
    <div class="loader-spiner-100" style="border-width: 10px;"></div>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="spiner-holder-1 animate-175-200-a">
   <div class="spiner-holder-2 animate-175-200-b">
    <div class="loader-spiner-100" style="border-width: 10px;"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spiner-holder-1 animate-200-225-a">
   <div class="spiner-holder-2 animate-200-225-b">
    <div class="loader-spiner-200" style="border-width: 10px;"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spiner-holder-1 animate-225-250-a">
   <div class="spiner-holder-2 animate-225-250-b">
    <div class="loader-spiner-200" style="border-width: 10px;"></div>
   </div>
  </div>


 </div>



</div>

<!--/progress bar animation-->

</div>
```